# Could you explain what mmap function do?

Tags: assembly, system-calls, mmap

What does it do this assembly code? I've analyzed code and  stopped at this moment. EDX is arg prot. ECX is arg length. ESI is arg flags. Am i right? But anyway i can't understand what does it do.

```
seg000:00000057                 push    ebp
seg000:00000058                 xor     ebp, ebp
seg000:0000005A                 xor     edi, edi
seg000:0000005C
seg000:0000005C 
seg000:0000005C                 dec     edi
seg000:0000005D                 mov     esi, 22h 
seg000:00000062                 mov     edx, 7    
seg000:00000067                 mov     ecx, 1000h      
seg000:0000006C                 xor     ebx, ebx        
seg000:0000006E                 mov     eax, 0C0h       
seg000:00000073                 int     80h       ;mmap      
seg000:00000075                 pop     ebp
seg000:00000076                 mov     edi, eax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calls `mmap(NULL, 0x1000, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)` which creates a single page of virtual memory and returns the virtual address of the page. If you want to know more about what mmap does, see https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap.